# Show today orders from table

Tags: php, mysql, date, int

I do not understand how to get output from  **my sql table**  .

the table  **date**  is stored in  **int**  . for example date output from one row is like  **1362157869** .

i want to  **show today orders**  in query :

```
   php : $today = date("y-m-d", time());

   query : SELECT * FROM test WHERE date = '$today'
```

but it  **didn't work** . i also try this :

```
    SELECT * FROM test WHERE date LIKE '$today'
```

Comment: Maybe adjust $today for format expected in base? I guess date is in `timestamp` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your date as a UNIXTIMESTAMP, so you have to convert it to DATETIME using FROM_UNIXTIME, and then you have to extract only the date part, ignoring the time, using the DATE() function:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = CURDATE()
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddf69/1). You can then extract yesterday records with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Or a specific date with this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = '2013-03-01'
```

**To make use of an index**

Assiming that your date column could contain not only the date part but also the time, you could also use this that will return all today records:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

and this for yesterday:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                         AND date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

or this for a specific date:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-01')
                         AND date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Query without PHP var:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date = DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: Does your date column include also the time ?

Comment: when orders insert in table date = time()

Comment: SELECT * FROM test WHERE date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());